# How do we create column from string where '\' is used to separate the sub string in SAS ?

Tags: sas

I have been trying to create columns in sas based on substring. I need to create a coloumn of each sub string stored in a column seprated by '\'.  For example:-

**prexa\Medical Information\Medical** Letters 02 is a single string stored in one column. i would like to have three columns col1: **prexa** col2 :**Medical Information** and Col3 : **Medical**. I am new to sas and have tried but unable to proceed.

this column  has numeric values with no sub string as well.

[content of coloumn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIytR.png)

Comment: Not easy to follow... Can you better explain "Letters 02 is a single string stored in one column"? And what about "This column has numeric values with no sub string as well"? Are you talking about your unsuccessful attempts?

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure this is what you're after, but might put you on the right track:

```
data have;
  informat str $60.;
  infile datalines dlm = "," truncover;
  input str;
  datalines;
prexa\Medical Information\Medical
some\other\string
run;

data want(drop = i);
  set have;
  array column(10) $ 32;
  do i = 1 to (count(str, "\") + 1);
    column(i) = scan(str, i, "\");
  end;
run;
```

In the ARRAY statement, replace 10 with the max number of columns you think you might need, and 32 with the max length of any column.

Results:

[image: Resulting dataset]